# Unable to load any webpages

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8, vpn, dns

I have trouble using the Internet using Wifi on my Windows 8 laptop.

It first happened about 2 days ago, everything was fine in the morning, but I was unable to connect to any webpages in the evening. There was the yellow error triangle icon over my wifi icon in the task tray, and it says "No Internet Access". I tried connecting directly to my router using a LAN cable, but still no Internet access. I thought it might be my NordVPN, and I uninstalled the NordVPN TAP, closed the NordVPN program, restarted the PC, and was able to connect to the Internet again.

Today, I was initially able to use the Internet (the pages loaded slower than usual, but they eventually loaded). However, after about an hour, I suddenly could not load any pages anymore. My Wifi is still connected to the Internet, but I couldn't access any websites.

The things I tried were

- Uninstall another program called "Tap for NordVPN". Not sure why there were 2 TAP programs, but this one has a different icon. It was
  an orange icon instead of NordVPN's blue icon.
- Uninstall the last few things I installed - Oracle VirtualBox, Npcap.
- I tried to uninstall Wireshark, but couldn't because `dumpcap.exe was still in use`. I couldn't kill `dumpcap.exe` using `wmic`, `taskkill` or PowerShell's `kill`, getting either the errors `Access is denied` or `No running instance`.
- I tried to uninstall NordVPN (though this has been running for a couple of years now), but the window stayed at "Loading" for a long time after I clicked "Uninstall" from the Control Panel.
- Remove NordVPN from startup list
- After each one, I would restart the laptop.

At this point, I can `ping 8.8.8.8`, but if I `ping www.google.com`, there is no response, no error message, just nothing. After some googling, I though it might have to do with my DNS client, as `ipconfig /displaydns`, `ipconfig /flushdns` and `ipconfig /registerdns` would return errors. The service was indeed disabled, so I restarted it, and ran the 3 `dns` commands, which were successful this time.

Still, I couldn't load any webpages, so I renewed my DHCP lease, and ran the 3 `dns` commands again. Still nothing. I can `ping` and even `tracert 8.8.8.8`, but not `dns.google`. I can also connect to my tablet using Airdroid using its IP address. I don't know what else I can try.

BTW, a few days before all of this, I had to reboot my laptop a couple of times after `DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION` errors, suddenly when I was browsing some webpages. Not sure if that's related.

Comment: Try the following:  Uninstall the wireless driver. Do not restart. Install the same or newer wireless driver (download from another source).  After install the wireless, restart and test the computer for wireless operation.

Comment: Have you tried to __Reset Winsock__ Windows Sockets... you can use __netsh winsock reset__ from a command prompt, then reboot your machine. Good luck.

Comment: 2.4 or 5.0? Sources of interference?